# Kubernetes : How to calculate Memory and CPU usage in terms of percentage for a given POD

Tags: kubernetes

Can someone please guide me, how to calculate the usage in terms of percentage [ CPU and Memory] for a POD with following available information

**kubectl top pods -n default**

```
NAME   CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
TEST   29m          13908Mi
```

**kubectl describe pod TEST**

```
Limits:
      cpu:  12
    Requests:
      cpu:     0
      memory:  13824Mi
```

Answer (score 1):

CPU is measured in milliCores. This means 1000m is 1 CPU 
Mi is, well, Mi.

For your Limits, you have no memory limit which means memory usage is unlimited and thus there is no memory usage percentage.
The CPU Limit percent would be 29 / (12 * 1000)

For the requests:
Since you requested 0 CPU, your request CPU % can't be determined (div by 0).
The memory request percent is 13908 / 13824 = 100%